# Buffering a YouTube video from a specific point

Tags: multithreading, youtube, buffer

I am working a little bit with the YouTube APIs and I was wondering if it was possible to have a video buffer from a specific point in one thread while still playing. For example, if I am watching a video from the beginning, while I am watching I want it to start buffering from 30 seconds concurrently while I watch my video.

Thank you

Comment: Sure.  You can have a queue of video buffers, why not?  Streaming video over variable-latency network links requires some such buffering anyway & so if you want to extend the buffering to 30 seconds worth, fine.

Comment: Can you have it buffer from two different parts of the same video simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Youtube API allows you to buffer only forward from the current point in the video.